# PHP preg_split Data

Tags: php

I have the following Data from .txt file:

```
10
std 2798.zip
std 3048.zip
std 3075.zip
std 3123.zip
std 3152.zip
std 3168.zip
std 3171.zip
std 3188.zip
std 3201.zip
-- Clustering --
{{std A.P.1810.zip,std A.P.2221.zip,std 2798.zip,std A.P. 3284.zip,std A.P.2812.zip,std AP 2616.zip,std 3244.zip,std AP 2516.zip},{std 3123.zip,std 3075.zip,std 3270.zip,std 3225.zip,std 3188.zip,std 3203.zip,std 3201.zip,std 3048.zip,std 3168.zip,std AEM_3252.zip,std AP 2427.zip,std 3152.zip,std 3171.zip}}
```

How can i use the preg_split to show the results as:

```
Array[0] std 2798.zip
Array[1] std 3048.zip
Array[2] std 3075.zip etc...
```

Also under the --Clustering --

```
Array[0] {std A.P.1810.zip, std A.P.2221.zip,std 2798.zip etc..},
Array[1] etc....
```

My code is:

```
echo "ole";

    $string=shell_exec("java -jar plagiarism.jar");
echo $string;
$oparray = preg_split("#[\r\n]+#", trim($string));
echo"<BR><BR>";

foreach ($oparray as $key)
{
    echo $key."   end\n";

    echo"<BR><BR>";

}
 ?>
```

Comment: What about `file` function and simple loop over result?

Comment: i edited my answer, if you mean this file function

Comment: it simply shows the number of the stds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the operating system, the end of line delimiter might values. Usually there are "line feed", "carriage return" and "carriage return-line feed". You need to split using any of these.

Here's a sample:

```
$string = <<<EOS
10
std 2798.zip
std 3048.zip
std 3075.zip
std 3123.zip
std 3152.zip
std 3168.zip
std 3171.zip
std 3188.zip
std 3201.zip
-- Clustering --
{{std A.P.1810.zip,std A.P.2221.zip,std 2798.zip,std A.P. 3284.zip,std A.P.2812.zip,std AP 2616.zip,std 3244.zip,std AP 2516.zip},{std 3123.zip,std 3075.zip,std 3270.zip,std 3225.zip,std 3188.zip,std 3203.zip,std 3201.zip,std 3048.zip,std 3168.zip,std AEM_3252.zip,std AP 2427.zip,std 3152.zip,std 3171.zip}}
EOS;

$parts  = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $string);

// get only those elements which start with std or {{
$result = array_filter($parts, function($element) {
    if (preg_match('/^(std|{{)/', $element)) {
        return $element;
    }
});

var_dump($result);
```